# How to press the back button programmatically in android

Tags: android

I want to know how to press the back button when a button is clicked in a service in android.
I want to make a program like assistive touch assistant in samsung phones..
Please help me!

Comment: **"...when a button is clicked in a service"** : What sort of a service are you using? The Android `Service` class doesn't have a user interface so it's not possible for a 'service' to have a button.

Comment: @Squonk Unless your service is using the WindowManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are no back buttons in a service.  A service does not have a UI.  If you mean an activity, just call `finish()`.

Comment: it's actually onBackPressed()

Comment: No, you should never call `onBackPressed()` yourself.

Comment: @KKD : The `onBackPressed` method is called automatically by the system and as kjkrum mentioned it shouldn't be called directly. More importantly, it doesn't trigger the press of the BACK button it is simply called as a result of an actual BACK press. Under normal circumstances pressing the BACK button simply finishes an `Activity` which in itself can be triggered by calling `finish()`.